# SAS Datetime and IF statements

Tags: datetime, sas

Hello I am trying to set a date 01/02/2015 to 01/09/2015. I am using a IF statement but I think since the column has as format of mmddyy10 and informat datetime20 its not working.

The column looks like this

```
01/09/2015
01/02/2015
05/23-2015
```

So I want it to look like this

```
01/09/2015
01/09/2015
05/23-2015
```

Is there a function in SAS that allows me to do this? Or will I have to convert the column to a Char and do my If statement that way.

Comment: INFORMAT might be a clue of a problem but it's not a problem technically.  INFORMAT is irrelevant after input.  The unformatted values are real dates (so something like 20435)?

Comment: Also, the final dash in the may dates isn't really possible - I assume that's a mistake.

Comment: What's the logic of setting the 2nd to the 9th? The 9th isn't incremented and they're both Friday's.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's a date value - so the unformatted value is something around 20000 - you can use date constant.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if datevar = '02JAN2015'd then datevar='09JAN2015'd;
run;
```

This is irrespective of the format applied to the column.  Format is *not* variable type; it's something like "When I look at this variable, please print it nicely using this format."  The underlying value is the same for all dates: some number of days since 1/1/1960.

Date *constants* are always represented using `DATE9.` format (`DDMONYYYY`).

If it's actually a datetime, then the format would not be `MMDDYY10.` but something else.  Then you use a datetime constant:

```
if datetimevar = '02JAN2015:00:00:00'dt then ...
```

or convert it to date using `datepart` first.

```
if datepart(datetimevar) = '02JAN2015'd then ...
```